# R Shiny Plotly 3D : Change the title of x , y , z axis to actual variable name and add legend title

Tags: r, 3d, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I have created a 3D scatter plot using `plotly()` on R shiny App. The code is as below :

```
output$threeDscatterPlot <- renderPlotly({
    data <- dataInput()$data
      plot.obj <<-list() 
      plot.obj$data <<- data 
      var7 <<- with(plot.obj$data,get(input$variable7)) 
      var8 <<- with(plot.obj$data,get(input$variable8)) 
      var9 <<- with(plot.obj$data,get(input$variable9)) 
      var10 <<- with(plot.obj$data,get(input$variable10)) 
      var10 <-  as.factor(var10)
      print(names(plot.obj$data))
p <- plot_ly(plot.obj$data, x = var7, y = var8 , z = var9 , type = "scatter3d", mode = "markers" , 
              color = var10 , colors = "Paired" ) 
       p %>%  layout(legend = list(x = 1, y = 0.5 , bgcolor = "#E2E2E2"))

 })
```

var7 , var8 , var9 are continous variable & var 10(categorical variable.

3D Plotly graph is coming very clearly but xaxis labels , yaxis labels and zaxis labels are comingas var 7 , var8 , var 9

My question is : 
How can we change the title of x , y , z axis to the actual variable name of var7/8/9 as in dataset/dataframe? I tried using xaxis .zaxis , yaxis but it does not seem to work
How can we add the legend title just above the legend?

All done in R Shiny App

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to your layout object:

```
layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'your title')))
```

more info here: https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-scene-xaxis-title